# Row of the character table of symmetric group with most negative entries

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

The row of the character table of $S_n$ corresponding to the trivial representation has all entries positive, and by orthogonality clearly it is the only one like this.

Is it true that for $n\gg 0$, the row of the character table of $S_n$ corresponding to the sign representation has the most negative entries of any row (about half of them)?

Note that for $S_4$, in addition to the sign representation row there are two other rows which also have 2 negative entries.

Possibly the fact that row sums are positive is relevant here.

Comment: Do we count each permutation once or each conjugacy class once?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: each conjugacy class. The character table is a $p(n)\times p(n)$ table, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$.

Comment: Some questions of a somewhat similar flavor that have been considered lately include whether most entries in the character table are highly divisible, or in fact are equal to $0$ (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.12410).

Comment: Is it clear/known that "about half of conjugacy classes have negative signature" ?

Comment: @DenisSerre: the sum of the row corresponding to the sign representation is https://oeis.org/A000700. This quantity grows much slower than $p(n)$, hence why I said “about half.”