Conjectures in the representation theory of the symmetric group

Question: What are current open conjectures about the representation theory of the symmetric group?

I am interested mostly in the characteristic 0 case, but conjectures for the modular case can also be presented.
Here is one conjecture for characteristic 0:

Saxl conjecture:  In characteristic 0, all irreducible representations of the symmetric group occur in the decomposition of the tensor square of the irreducible representation given by the staircase partition.

See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.13769 .
Here a nice conjecture in the modular case:

No loop conjecture: The quiver of the group algebra of the symmetric group has no loops in characteristic not equal to two.

See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12961
(It might be also be interesting to see some group theoretic conjecture, if there are any open conjectures left for the symmetric group).

Nice question ! Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/96202/10446,  and also not about representation theory per se, but important conjecture about symmetric group diameters of Cayley graphs: https://mathoverflow.net/a/103490/10446

I believe Sheila Sundaram has some interesting conjectures: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.01416.pdf

If we're counting the behavior of the character tables of $S_n$ as part of the representation theory of $S_n$, recently Peluse and Soundararajan resolved a conjecture of Miller, showing that almost all entries in this character table are divisible by any fixed prime power as $n$ goes to infinity: https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.02203. The question of whether almost all entries are zero remains an interesting open question (although I guess not exactly a conjecture because I don't know anyone who has conjectured the answer either way).

Also, again about character tables, and apologies for promoting my own question (I don't think it's super important in any way but I do think it's cute): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420865. I've asked some experts about this and they don't seem to know how to use known tools to attack it.

Now, in terms of the modular representation theory of the symmetric groups, there are very very basic questions that are open (see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458191 or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138310).

Not a conjecture per se, but a fundamental open problem in the representation theory of $S_n$ is to give a combinatorial interpretation of the Kronecker coefficients $g_{\lambda,\mu,\nu}=\langle \chi^\lambda \chi^\mu,\chi^\nu\rangle$.

Just a few things that come to my mind; most are about the base ring $\mathbb{Z}$, but a good answer would tell us something interesting about $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.

Specht modules can be defined not just for partitions and for skew partitions, but for any shape, i.e., any finite set of "boxes" in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. For example, you can define it as the span of the polytabloids in the module of tabloids, or you can (equivalently) define it as the left ideal of the symmetric group algebra generated by the Young symmetrizer $b_T a_T$, where $T$ is any tableau of the given shape, $a_T$ is its row-symmetrizer and $b_T$ is its column-antisymmetrizer. For details, see §1.2 of Ricky Ini Liu, Specht modules and Schubert varieties for general diagrams, thesis 2010. How does such a general Specht module decompose into irreducibles? Even more basically, what is a basis of this module? Can its dimension depend on the characteristic of the base field? Various particular cases have been studied, such as the %-avoiding shapes (Reiner/Shimozono 1998).

The Gelfand-Zetlin subalgebra of the group algebra $\mathbb Z\left[S_n\right]$ is the subring (= $\mathbb Z$-subalgebra) generated by the Young-Jucys-Murphy elements $m_k := t_{1,k} + t_{2,k} + \cdots + t_{k-1,k}$, where $t_{i,j}$ is the transposition swapping $i$ with $j$. What is a basis of this subalgebra as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module? Is it a saturated $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule (i.e., a direct summand of $\mathbb Z\left[S_n\right]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module)? Note that over $\mathbb{Q}$, it has a well-known basis, namely the diagonal part of the seminormal basis of $\mathbb Q\left[S_n\right]$ (that is, the family $\left(e_{T,T}\right)$ with $T$ ranging over the standard tableaux with $n$ cells).


EDIT: See https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/nfe2024.pdf for more details on these problems (and a third one on the group ring of $S_n$, albeit not representation-theoretical).

These are interesting questions, but are there conjectures here?

1 can be straightforwardly stated as a conjecture (the independence of the dimension on the characteristic, or the existence of a $\mathbb Z$-basis that remains a basis upon base change), and I have in fact heard experts make this conjecture.

For 2, the conjecture should be that the Gelfand-Zetlin subalgebra is free of rank the number of standard tableaux of size $n$ or, equivalently, the number of transpositions in $\mathfrak{S}_n$. It would be nice to have generators and relations too:) The Young-Jucys-Murphy elements generate, and I can give some relations, but I have no idea if these are sufficient.

@Andrew can you elaborate (perhaps by email?) on the topic of relations you know?

@Andrew I, too, am interested!

The obvious relations are that the YJM-elements commute.  Less obvious relations are their minimum polynomials in the semisimple setting, which are integral and so make sense over any ring. See Corollary 2.17 of my paper "Matrix units and generic degrees for the Ariki-Koike algebras", J. Algebra 281 (2004), no. 2, 695–730. This is in a slightly more general setting, with the symmetric group being a special case.

@Andrew: These I'm aware of, but there are more. For instance, $\left(1+m_2\right)\left(1+m_3\right)\left(m_3-2\right) = 0$ holds because $\left(1+m_2\right)\left(1+m_3\right)$ is the sum of all permutations of $\left{1,2,3\right}$. This does not follow from the commutativity and the minimal polynomials.

@darijgrinberg Agreed. I was thinking more generally of relations "of this form" that involve contents. For example, if $\mathsf{t}$ is a standard tableau and $c_k(\mathsf{t})$ is the content of $k$ in $\mathsf{t}$ then $\prod_{k=1}^n\bigl(L_k-c_k(\mathsf{t})\bigr)=0$. However, this gives many relations, especially as you can consider tableaux of sizes $m\le n$...

@Andrew: What do you mean by this equality? Isn't the first factor already zero? On the other hand, the idea you're suggesting looks good: Any set $S$ of pairs $\left(k,i\right)$ such that each standard tableau with $n$ cells has at least one cell with entry $k$ and content $i$ will necessarily satisfy $\prod_{\left(k,i\right) \in S} \left(m_k - i\right) = 0$ (my $m_k$ is your $L_k$). It would be interesting to describe the (or at least some) minimal sets $S$ with this property.

@darijgrinberg For the YJM elements of thesytmmetric groups I agree that $L_1=0$ (sorry, I'm unable to write $m_k$...), so these relations automatically hold. Rather, I am asking if, as an abstract algebra, $\operatorname{GZ}n$ has a presentation that looks something like $$\bigl\langle, L_k\bigm| L_jL_k=L_kL_j, \prod{k=1}^n\bigl(L_k-c_k(\mathsf{t})\bigr)=0,\bigr\rangle,$$where $\mathsf{t}$ runs over the standard tableaux. I have not done any experiments, so this is a really naive and unfounded question:)

Here are some of my favorites, some were mentioned in comments already. I'm not going to be too picky about the distinction between conjectures vs open questions.
The Saxl Conjecture was already mentioned, but there is also the closely related Tensor Square Conjecture which states that for all sufficiently large $n$ there is some irreducible representation $\chi_\lambda$ such that the tensor square $\chi_\lambda^{\otimes 2}$ contains every irreducible representation with positive multiplicity.  I'd go a step further to make what might be called the Strong Tensor Square Conjecture that if you choose an irreducible representation at random from the Plancharel measure, then it satisfies the tensor square property as a representation of the alternating group with probability tending to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.   The alternating group modification is needed to deal with the sign representation.
There is also the Strengthened Saxl conjecture due to Bessenrodt, Bowman, and Sutton, which says that over a field of characteristic 2, the tensor square of the Specht module corresponding to a staircase partition contains every simple $2$-modular representation as a submodule (or quotient, equivalently). I'll note that we already know it they all appear as subquotients rather than submodules, and that if true this conjecture would imply the ordinary Saxl conjecture via a lifting to Witt vectors argument.
The Foulkes Conjecture relates the plethysms $s_a[s_b]$ and $s_b[s_a]$. In terms of symmetric group representations these correspond to the permutation representations of $S_{ab}$ acting on the set of (unordered) set-partitions of $[ab]$ into $a$ parts of size $b$, or $b$ parts of size $a$. There is a natural candidate map $\psi_{a,b}$ between them that sends a set-partition of one type to the sum of all "transversal"  set partitions of the other type. By transversal I mean that the intersection of any part from the first set-partition with a part from the second set-partition has size $1$. A strengthening of the Foulkes conjecture, sometimes called the Foulkes-Howe Conjecture is that this map $\psi_{a,b}$ has full rank whenever $a \ne b$.
Alex Miller has conjectured that the number of zero entries in the character table of $S_n$ divided by the total number of entries approaches a positive value as $n \to \infty$, it is stated as a question in the paper but he has publicly stated it as a conjecture.  However another expert I've spoken to has conjectured the opposite, that the proportion of zero entries tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (but slowly). I won't say who the second person is since I don't know if they want their name publicly associated to that conjecture, but I've heard convincing sounding heuristics for both directions.
In a similar vein to the Kronecker coefficient and plethysm questions, there is The Restriction Problem which asks for a combinatorial description of the branching rule from polynomial representations of $GL_n$ to $S_n$, sitting inside it as permutation matrices. I'll note that a combinatorial interpretation for plethysm coefficients would solve this as well, but there is reason to suspect this might be easier than the general case.
There are the questions of understanding Decomposition Numbers and Characters Formulas for simple $p$-modular representations.  There are now some conjectures and theorems relating them to some pretty subtle things like p-Kazhdan-Lusztig bases, but we are very far away from a combinatorial interpretation.  Still though, a wildly optimistic hope would be to show the dimension of an irreducible $D^\lambda$ is counted by standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$, subject to certain mod-p vanishing or non-vanishing conditions on the contents, hook lengths, or other combinatorial statistics.

The original Foulke-Howe Conjecture was that the map has full rank for any $a,b$. Do you know where the $a\neq b$ weakened version was first stated as a conjecture?

No. I've not seen the weaker version stated as a conjecture explicitly anywhere, but I would say it is implicit in the approach of Cheung, Ikenmeyer, and Mkrtchyan here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03944.pdf

That was my guess.

There are several conjectures in this area that pertain to computational complexity. Most well known are those that arise from geometric complexity theory à la Mulmuley and Sohoni. The original versions of some of these conjectures, involving so-called "occurrence obstructions," have been disproved, but more nuanced versions, involving multiplicity obstructions, remain open.
In a comment, Richard Stanley mentions the problem of finding a combinatorial interpretation of Kronecker coefficients. In the same breath, one might also mention the problem of finding a combinatorial interpretation of plethysm coefficients. Igor Pak has boldly conjectured that in both cases, no such combinatorial interpretation exists. First he argues that if there exists a combinatorial interpretation, then the problem of computing the coefficients would lie in the complexity class $\mathsf{\#P}$. (This part of the argument is partly linguistic, since it turns on one's understanding of what a "combinatorial interpretation" is.) Then he conjectures that computing Kronecker/plethysm coefficients is not in $\mathsf{\#P}$. It is probably unreasonable to hope for an unconditional proof of this latter claim, but one could hope to prove that the problem is complete for some counting class that is believed to strictly contain $\mathsf{\#P}$.

The representation theory relevant to the geometric complexity theory you discuss in the first paragraph is that of $GL_n$, no? I guess, via Schur-Weyl duality, symmetric functions, etc. this can be translated to saying something about symmetric groups, but I'm not sure that's the most natural setting for posing these problems.

@SamHopkins Some of the negative results of Ikenmeyer and Panova were framed in terms of Kronecker coefficients, which I think of as being about symmetric groups.
